# A term for the focal point for considering ancestors and descendents

Tags: terminology

Going to try my best to describe my question in a half decent way.

Is there a generic term for the subject you are using to define the ancestor/descendent relationship?

Or, another way:
If I'm the focal point that defines everyone before me as ancestors, and after me as descendants, do I have a term like ancestor and descendant?

Comment: @Cascabel "Family" would include siblings, etc. which is not what OP is looking for.

Comment: I can't find a perfect match, but perhaps the closest would be: "ancestral lineage", meaning any lineage which includes you. Perhaps it's a bit of a stretch, though...

Comment: On an Ahnentafel, which is one of the standard ways of presenting ancestors, the person whose ancestry is given is person number 1. Father is 2, mother 3, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If I'm the focal point that defines everyone..."

***locus***

-the place where something happens ***or the central area of interest in something being discussed:***

[-Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/locus)

Another suggestion...

[***nexus***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nexus)

> an important connection between the parts of a system or a group of things:

These are general terms: There is probably no single word to describe a family relationship of this type.